# "gradle init" (v4.0) generated build.gradle can't find packages

Tags: java, gradle

I converted a working Maven project to Gradle using "gradle init."  I'm getting package does not exist errors.  I'm not sure how to debug this error.

```
$ ./gradlew build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :drill-logical:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
/home/drill/logical/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/common/expression/LogicalExpression.java:26: error: package org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser does not exist
import org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser.ExprLexer;
                                                ^
/home/drill/logical/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/common/expression/LogicalExpression.java:27: error: package org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser does not exist
import org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser.ExprParser;
                                                ^
/home/drill/logical/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/common/expression/LogicalExpression.java:28: error: package org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser.ExprParser does not exist
import org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser.ExprParser.parse_return;
                                                           ^
/home/drill/logical/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/common/expression/SchemaPath.java:29: error: package org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser does not exist
import org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser.ExprLexer;
                                                ^
/home/drill/logical/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/common/expression/SchemaPath.java:30: error: package org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser does not exist
import org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser.ExprParser;
                                                ^
/home/drill/logical/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/common/expression/SchemaPath.java:31: error: package org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser.ExprParser does not exist
import org.apache.drill.common.expression.parser.ExprParser.parse_return;
                                                           ^
```

The build.gradle in the drill/logical directory:

```
 $ cat build.gradle

 description = 'Logical Plan, Base expressions'
 dependencies {
     compile project(':drill-protocol')
     compile project(':drill-common')
     compile(group: 'org.apache.calcite', name: 'calcite-core', version:'1.4.0-drill-r21') {
         exclude(module: 'jgrapht-jdk1.5')
         exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
         exclude(module: 'jackson-annotations')
         exclude(module: 'jackson-core')
         exclude(module: 'jackson-databind')
     }

     compile group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version:'1.0.0'
     compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version:'3.1'
     compile group: 'org.msgpack', name: 'msgpack', version:'0.6.6'
     compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version:'0.9.8'
     compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version:'2.7.1'
     compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.7.1'
     compile group: 'com.codahale.metrics', name: 'metrics-core', version:'3.0.1'
     compile group: 'com.codahale.metrics', name: 'metrics-servlets', version:'3.0.1'
     compile group: 'org.antlr', name: 'antlr-runtime', version:'3.4'
     compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version:'2.9'

     testCompile project(':drill-common')
 }

 task packageTests(type: Jar) {
     from sourceSets.test.output
     classifier = 'tests'
 }
```

Am I looking at the wrong build.gradle file?  The uppermost build.gradle lists the dependencies and repositories which appear to match it's pom.xml one-to-one.

What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes you are missing are generated by ANTLR. You have an ANTLR grammar file in your repo from which those sources are generated. Like most plugins that are used in Maven builds, this is not transported to Gradle automatically but has to be done manually. Use the Gradle ANTLR plugin that is builtin to generate the sources from the grammar files.

Comment: Adding the antlr plugin,  the "generateGrammarSource" and setting the dependency of the java compile to generateGrammarSource did not change the error.

Comment: I don't think you need anything besides applying the plugin. I think everything else like dependencies and so on should be set automatically. If it still does not work, please provide current build script and execution output with `-i` and `-d` separately, or simply tell me where I can pull your current drill state to have a look.

Comment: Using the -i  option, I see the problem.  Although I've set the source directory, "logical/src/main/antlr3", Gradle insists on using "logical/src/main/antlr".  A symlink from "antlr3" to "antlr" fixed the problem.

Comment: How did you set the source directory?

Comment: Inside "task gerateGrammarSource" I set the antlr.srcDirs to the $projectDir/src/main/antlr3/org/apache/drill/common/expression/parser, but during the build, gradle insisted on using  $projectDir/src/main/antlr/org/apache/drill/common/expression/parser.   A symlink from antlr3 to antlr got me past that point.